# Remove item from array on timeout

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a component to display notifications that should dismiss automatically after a few seconds in Vue, my alert components emits an 'expired' event and then I listen for this event in the parent, and remove it from the parent data array with splice, this works sometimes but sometimes the 'alerts' are not removed.

```
Vue.component('alert', {
  template: '<li><slot></slot></li>',
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => this.$emit('expired'), 2000)
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 0,
    alerts: []
  },
  methods: {
        createAlert(){
        this.alerts.push(this.count++)
      },
      removeItem(index) {
        this.alerts.splice(index, 1)
      }
  }
});
```

See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enriqg9/vyk7py4w/) and click on the `Create Alert` button a couple of times, and some of the alerts won't get dismissed. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Hint: When an item is removed from an array, what happens to the indices of the items after it?

Comment: @nnnnnn they reset and start from 0 again, but then how can I delete an specific item if there are no associative arrays in javascript?

Comment: I don't know enough about Vue to know what the "approved" Vue approach is, but JS does have objects, so perhaps one approach would be to have an array of objects with an `id` and `text` property (or whatever), and in the remove function search the array for the object with the right `id`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, don't do this by index. Here is one alternative.

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="createAlert">
    Create Alert
  </button>
  <alert v-for="(alert, index) in alerts" :key="alert.id" :alert="alert" @expired="removeItem(alert)">{{ alert.id }}</alert>
</div>

Vue.component('alert', {
  props: ["alert"],
  template: '<li><slot></slot></li>',
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => this.$emit('expired', alert), 2000)
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 0,
    alerts: []
  },
  methods: {
        createAlert(){
        this.alerts.push({id: this.count++})
      },
      removeItem(alert) {
        this.alerts.splice(this.alerts.indexOf(alert), 1)
      }
  }
});
```

[Your fiddle revised](https://jsfiddle.net/x0z2dgbm/2/).

Comment: Thank you, can you explain what is the `key` property used here for?

Comment: @enriqg9 Whenever you use a `v-for` you *should* be using a `key` property to help Vue identify the correct node to add/remove from a list. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key

Comment: From the documentation now, "In 2.2.0+, when using v-for with a component, a key is now required."  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: I just realized you answered my last Vue question as well, so double thanks!

Comment: @enriqg9 no problem :)